# Magento 1.9 robots.txt seo

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, robots.txt

I think i have a problem with robots.txt in magento 1.9.3.4

In Search Console at Index Status of https version i see this:
[image]

Is it a issue? and if yes, how can i solve it?

http:
[image]

### Robots.txt

```
# Website Sitemap
Sitemap: https://domain/sitemap.xml
 
# Crawlers Setup
User-agent: *
#Crawl-delay: 10
 
# Allowable Index
# Mind that Allow is not an official standard
Allow: /*?p=
Allow: /index.php/blog/
Allow: /catalog/seo_sitemap/category/
# Allow: /catalogsearch/result/
Allow: /media/catalog/
 
# Directories
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /app/
 
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /downloader/
 
Disallow: /errors/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /magento/
# Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /media/captcha/
# Disallow: /media/catalog/
#Disallow: /media/css/
#Disallow: /media/css_secure/
Disallow: /media/customer/
Disallow: /media/dhl/
Disallow: /media/downloadable/
Disallow: /media/import/
#Disallow: /media/js/
Disallow: /media/pdf/
Disallow: /media/sales/
Disallow: /media/tmp/
Disallow: /media/wysiwyg/
Disallow: /media/xmlconnect/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /shell/
#Disallow: /skin/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /var/
 
# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /index.php/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/gallery/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /control/
Disallow: /contacts/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customize/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /poll/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /sendfriend/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /wishlist/
 
# Files
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /STATUS.txt
Disallow: /get.php # Magento 1.5+
 
# Paths (no clean URLs)
#Disallow: /*.js$
#Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*?SID=
Disallow: /rss*
Disallow: /*PHPSESSID
```

Comment: Can you add a copy of your robots.txt to check what urls are you blocking, have into mind if you are blocking non-seo urls but at the same time you are serving content with non-seo urls then the amount of page blocked will be a lot for bots

Comment: i don't know if it safe to provide a link to site here

Answer (score 1):

this line will block crawlers to get your images from cms pages and blocks:
Disallow: /media/wysiwyg/

and if you have a page the search terms page and/or a cloud of most search terms this will also cause many blocks to crawlers:
Disallow: /catalogsearch/

All the rest looks fine, about the url, it's fine, just check that your product and category pages have SEO friendly urls (something like my-nice-product.html instead of .../catalog/product/view/... or /women.html instead of .../catalog/category/view/...)

Comment: I think it is ok, right? https://www.diapasonhifi.gr/ so.... i must to comment this lines, i understand right? #Disallow: /media/wysiwyg/ #Disallow: /catalogsearch/

Comment: Yes Pantelis, comment first line, all the rest looks fine and you haven't a search terms page or cloud so it's fine Disallow: /catalogsearch/